# Azure Data Lake - Generate *Connection string* using the available credential keys

Tags: python, authentication, azure-data-lake

I am trying to connect to Azure data lake storage using *connection_string* with my personal account. Using which, I can make connection and work with blobs.

Now, I have received below 4 keys and want to see if there is function we can generate *connection_string*  from it using python?

I know, I can use the keys and work with it. But wanted to explore if there is this option available.

Python code:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

TENANT_ID = 'XXX'
CLIENT_ID = 'XXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXX'
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'XXX'

credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME), credential=credential)
```

Comment: what do you mean connection_string url? is it just a connection string ?

Comment: My bad, yes connection string.

Comment: No, we cannot do that. Please refer to answer below. If it's helpful, please accept it as answer:) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The `connection string` and the `service principal`(the keys you mentioned like `CLIENT_ID` / `CLIENT_SECRET`) are different authorization solution, you cannot convert one to another.

By the way, to authenticate the client you have a few options, and you cannot mix them:

1.Use a SAS token string

2.Use an account shared access key

3.Use a token credential from `azure.identity`(like using service principal)

4.Connection string

Comment: This is helpful. The hidden reason behind asking this question was that using service principal keys I am unable to connect to ADLS and clueless what might be missing. But with my another personal ADLS account I can connect seamless with ADLS using connection string. Any idea what should be my debugging steps for service principal credentials?

Comment: @nikhil I'll take a look later and then update you:).